# Why does "Require all denied" in apache2.conf apply to all sub-directories?

Tags: apache, require

I'd like to understand this behaviour which does not make sense to me.

apache2.conf has the default configuration at the bottom.

As you can see, it has "Require all denied" for / and "Require all granted" for /var/www/

I have a website under /var/www/HM/

After using URL rewriting, Apache is asked to send the result of for example /var/www/HM/subdir/

Instead of correctly returning the content of index.php located in subdir, it denies access. I found out that the / "Require all denied" config in apache2.conf is to blame, but this does not make sense to me especially as "Require all granted" is given to /var/www/

I have managed to set "Require all granted" for /var/www/HM/ and it seems to work then. But still I'd like to understand why the / directive in apache2.conf applies to everything below and that the /var/www/ directive does not!

Also if the directive for /var/www/ does not apply to sub-directories, I wonder if my directive for /var/www/HM/ will apply to its own sub-directories...

Thanks for your help!

```
# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) states that the `Directory` directive includes sub-directories:

> Enclose a group of directives that apply only to the named file-system
> directory, **sub-directories**, and their contents.

I skimmed a bit through the apache-httpd code and couldn't find any special handling of the root directory or any other directory. (okay okay, root is special: it's always first in the directory list)

Also: experience tells me that you probably had another `Directory` directive in another config file that messed up the directory permissions, or a `.htaccess` in the subdirectory with `Deny from all` specified.